# The requested application is unavailable or does not exist

Tags: ios, flutter, testflight

While everything was normal until last night, my TestFlight versions for all my applications were expired after a version I installed last night, and the newly installed versions are not usable in TestFlight. I get the error "The requested application is unavailable or does not exist". I tried to contact Apple officials, but I did not receive any response.

How can I get rid of this error?